# Problems with Recursive Multiplicative Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, fibonacci, multiplication

I am writing a recursive method that will calculate a multiplicative Fibonacci Sequence.  This sequence is similar to a regular Fibonacci Sequence except that instead of adding the two previous numbers to find the next numbers, you instead multiply them. I currently have this method written but instead of returning what I would think the correct result is, the method is returning 0 no matter what the input number is.  Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. 
Here is the method:

```
public static int fibonacciPower(int n)
{
    if(n < 2)
    {
        return n;
    }
    else
    {
        return (fibonacciPower(n-1) * fibonacciPower(n-2));
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that Fibonacci is an algorithm for which recursion is a pretty horrible implementation, generally speaking.

Comment: Where do you call the method? With what value?

Comment: @Servy tail recursion seems fine to me...

Comment: @Theolodis Fib(5) computes Fib(4) and Fib(3).  Fib(4) computes Fib(3) (again) and Fib(2).  Fib(3) (run twice) computes Fib(2) (computed both for Fib(4) and twice in Fib(3)).  I hope you get the idea.  It actually turns an O(n) operation into an O(2^n) operation.  That is, unless you cache all previously computed values, but if you do that, the memory footprint goes from O(1) (with an iterative solution) to O(n).

Comment: That's called tail recursion....

Comment: @Theolodis No, it's not.  Tail recursion is related to consuming stack space when no stack space is actually needed, because none of the stack data is consumed in subsequent methods.  Using a tail recursive method in a language without tail call optimization needlessly consumes more stack than it needs to, but it doesn't have anything to do with computing the same function multiple times.  Given that this method would be prohibitively expensive to compute well before you could actually blow out the stack, the lack of tail call optimization actually *isn't* a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return 1

```
if(n < 2)
{
    return 1;
}
```

This is because, if n becomes 0, you end up multiplying by 0 and in turn your product becomes 0. Thus instead we multiply with 1 in case of n equal to 0 or 1

Comment: Beyond that, the formal definition of Fibonacci simply defines Fib(0) to be 1.

Comment: @Theolodis Well, it would be 1,1,1,1,1, it wouldn't start with zero, but that's simply the correct result of the algorithm defined.  If 0 is 1 and 1 is 1 and everything else is the product of the two previous values, you'll never get anything other than 1.  So you could just replace the method with `return 1;` if you wanted.

Comment: Looks like someones one a down-voting spree.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi Not quite.  A few of them are mine, for those that clearly misunderstood the question.  Some of them are from someone else though

Comment: @Ankit You pointed me in the right direction, so thanks for the help!  Here is the code I have come up with to solve the problem  public static int fibonacciPower(int n)
 {
  if(n < 2)
  {
   return 1;
  }
  if(n == 2)
  {
   return 2;
  }
  else
  {
  return (fibonacciPower(n-1) * fibonacciPower(n-2));
  }
 }       This method sets the first number in the sequence equal to 1 and the second number equal to 2.

Comment: @user2932450 There is no need for your second `if`.  You don't need to handle the case of `2` at all, just let it recurse.  Also, given the definition of the function you defined, your method should return `1` when `n` is `2`, it shouldn't return `2`.  Fib(2) is Fib(1) * Fib(0), and Fib(1) and Fib(0) are both `1`.  1*1 = 1, not 2.

Comment: @Servy Do I miss something or is there any valid solution at all for the Fibonacci recursive method, that instead of addition uses multiplication. Never heard of it before.

Comment: @informatik01 I have never heard of such a function before myself, and given that it doesn't return anything useful, I'm not surprised by that at all.

Comment: @Servy That's what I thought. Initially I thought it's just an ordinary university/college assignment to implement classical recursive Fibonacci function, but seems like the way the OP wants it is just some fantasy.